# Xcode unity build failed "UNITY_VERSION_VER, UNITY_VERSION_MAJ, UNITY_VERSION_MIN must be set in xcode project, something went wrong"

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

created IOS build using Unity trying to run this xcode getting following error

**"UNITY_VERSION_VER, UNITY_VERSION_MAJ, UNITY_VERSION_MIN must be set in xcode project, something went wrong"**

following is the code which auto generated

```
#if !defined(UNITY_VERSION_VER) || !defined(UNITY_VERSION_MAJ) || !defined(UNITY_VERSION_MIN)
#error "UNITY_VERSION_VER, UNITY_VERSION_MAJ, UNITY_VERSION_MIN must be set in xcode project, something went wrong"
#endif
```

Unity version is already there in the Xcode project
[image]

Using unity version **2022.1.014b**

how to fix this?

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

You defined UNITY_RUNTIME_VERSION but that doesn’t match any of the names that you need. Rename that value to UNITY_VERSION_VER

Comment: Actually this is auto generated by unity

Answer (score 0):

1.Add macro definitions for "UNITY_VESION_VER, UNITY_VESION_MAJ, UNITY_VESION_MIN" to Prefix.pch
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vldYG.png)

2.Delete the existing Prefix.pch.gch from the directory as prompted for recompilation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e8kJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

After Adding macro definitions getting error in xcode "Reference to 'ReentrantLock' is ambiguous"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).